# Horizontal align of the legend. Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am not able to do a proper horizontal align, what am I missing?.

```
legend: {
        align: 'middle',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: 50,
        symbolHeight: 20
  },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Ajnn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Align should be `center` when referred to horizontal placement and `middle` when referring to vertical.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.align

```
    legend: {
        align: 'center',

        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: 50,
        symbolHeight: 20
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/2Ajnn/1/

Comment: Thanks, but its still ugly, cant give it more space between the heat map and the legend? and could I make the legend bigger? (longer)

Comment: Of course, you can just play with the various settings such as `margin, symbolHeight, symbolWidth, y` etc etc. Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/2Ajnn/2/ Documentation here http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#legend

Comment: The problem its that there is not space to make it bigger, its not showed because its out of the frame, whats the way to solve that?

Comment: Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/2Ajnn/2/ and then search through the JS of that demo for all occurences of margin, symbolHeight, symbolWidth, y etc etc as I have already mentioned and you will be able to play around to get it just how you want it!

Comment: Sorry, but actually I have got all the options like there and I dont manage to show the legend completely, I guess its for the different size between jsfiddle and my browser. I dont get how can I set a size for the legend framework, I understand I can set the global size of the heat map, but its 99% used by the cells and just a little space down for the legend.

Comment: Everything you need has been given to you.  If you want professional consultancy it's not that hard to find.

Comment: example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ajnn/3/ That legend its a very slim line in a normal browser, if you make it thicker it goes out of the framework

Comment: OK - on one of my bigger screens https://www.anonimg.com/img/c5cfdffb6a0c18431115a919455f113d.png
and on same screen, window made quite small and then fiddle reloaded and scrolled down https://www.anonimg.com/img/253ae6fc1572cc1df997972badf6b66e.png  so what's the problem?

Comment: I meant on my site, same configuration: https://www.anonimg.com/img/3f6e95fb188dd3013d70f74b00edfbea.png  if I increase symbolHeight, ops, xAxis categories overlapped, lets increase "y" then, ops, legend not shown anymore because it goes out of the frame

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57414/discussion-between-rob-schmuecker-and-pedro4441).